# mysql: How to create a calculated field that looks up a value from another table

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

Apologies for the clumsy question. I am trying to setup a calculated field that looks up a value in another table. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
 ALTER TABLE `DBname`.`MyTable`  ADD COLUMN `NewValue` decimal(7,2) AS
 (`SomeValue` * SELECT `ReferenceValue` FROM `DBname`.`OtherTable`
 WHERE `RecordID`="WJANtdzl";
          ) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: A generated column?

Comment: 'Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: You need to create a view, you can have such a calculated field there. At the moment this is not possible via generated columns.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @P.Salmon.